# Meteor - When running the "Meteor" error occurs

Tags: meteor

I actually do not know how I messed things up with meteor, I did not touch anything related to meteor for all I know.  Today all of a sudden my text editor, Atom stopped opening. This required me to spend all day to search for reasons why it didn't work and eventually I got it working again but I had to delete a lot of files related to Atom.  After I got Atom up and working again, I went to run my app, but it did not run.  Instead, game me an error that is super long:

```
Error: SQLITE_CORRUPT: database disk image is malformed
```

and also gives some other unreadable text.  But it does say something about the `promise_server.js:218` file.  I also read on this forum that you can use a command like `rm rf` or something like that I cannot find the forum where it said that again.... but it did not work.  I have run out of possible solutions, if you know what is going on, pls help.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should help:

```
cd <your_meteor_project_folder>
rm -rf ./.meteor
```

Then restart your meteor app.

Comment: What OS are you using? You can just navigate into your project folder and remove `.meteor` directory.

Comment: I'm using windows.  Will removing the directory cause me to lose the libraries installed in my project folder? And also what will removing it do?

Comment: When I run some of my other apps, it starts up just fine...Could it be a problem with my code?

Comment: Nvm it works now, i had to uninstall and install meteor again.. now it gives this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined" any fixes.  Did some research no one could find a solution without restarting their entire project.

Comment: You can remove just `.meteor/local` directory, this way you won't lose your installed meteor packages.

Comment: Well I already deleted the entire .meteor folder, and it returns the error about meteor install as mentioned above in the browser.  How do I fix that? It also gives me errors about the promise.js file still in the browser

Comment: You should provide the entire error log, otherwise it's impossible to guess your problem. I'd recommend open another question for that and provide as much info as you can.

Comment: I would've but it is extremely long and my command line does not allow me to copy text from the console

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlite3 you can repair the DB.

```
cd ~/.meteor/package-metadata/v2.0.1
sqlite3 packages.data.db .dump > backup
mv packages.data.db packages.data.db.bustedX
sqlite3 packages.data.db < backup
rm backup
```

Essentially, even though the DB reports as corrupt.  The SQLite tool can dump it and then recreate it.